# php array lastfit in bin packing based on price

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
 $products = array( 
   array('name'=>item1, 'price'=>20),
   array('name'=>item2, 'price'=>100),
   array('name'=>item3, 'price'=>130),
   array('name'=>item4, 'price'=>200),
 );
?>
```

i want to grouping or sorting array into table where each table of total price can not be greater than 250

```
--------------------------
|        Group 1         |
--------------------------
|  Name     |    Price   |
--------------------------
| Item 3    |    130     |
--------------------------
| Item 2    |    100     |
--------------------------
Total Items  : 2
-------------------------
Total Price : 230
---------------------------



--------------------------
|        Group 2         |
--------------------------
|  Name     |    Price   |
--------------------------
| Item 4    |    200     |
--------------------------
| Item 1    |    20      |
--------------------------
Total Items  : 2
--------------------------
Total Price : 220
--------------------------
```

You can see in the above example group 1 total price is 230 which is less than 250 and in group 2 the total price is 220 which is also less than 250
please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point:

```
$max = 250;
$i = 1;
$total = 0;
$group = [];
foreach ($products as $p) {
    $total += $p['price'];
    if ($total >= $max) {
        $total = $p['price'];
        $i++;
    }
    $groups[$i][] = $p; 
}
```

Next you need to iterate(for example: foreach) $groups and echo the data as you wish

Comment: result is not as what i want.       -------    your out put is :   Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => item1 [price] => 20 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => item2 [price] => 100 ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => item3 [price] => 130 ) ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => item4 [price] => 200 ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea from this :

```
<?php

 $maxPrice = 250;
 $chunks = array();
 $total = 0;
 $products = array( 
   array('name'=>'item1', 'price'=>20),
   array('name'=>'item2', 'price'=>100),
   array('name'=>'item3', 'price'=>130),
   array('name'=>'item4', 'price'=>200),
 );
 $group = 1;
 foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($total + $product['price'] > $maxPrice) {
        $total = 0;
        $group++;
    }
    $total += $product['price'];
    $chunks[$group][] = $product;
 }
 if($chunks) {
     $totalPrice = 0;

     foreach($chunks as $group=>$products) {
         $totalPrice = 0;
         echo '<table border="1">';
         echo '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Group '.$group.'</td></tr>';
         echo '<tr><td>Name</td><td>Price</td></tr>';
         foreach($products as $product) {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td >'.$product['name'].'</td>';
             echo '<td >'.$product['price'].'</td>';
             echo '</tr>';
             $totalPrice += $product['price'];
         }
         echo '<tr><td colspan="2">Total Items : '.count($products).'</td></tr>';
         echo '<tr><td colspan="2">Total Price : '.$totalPrice.'</td></tr>';
         echo '</table>';
     }
 }
?>
```

Comment: hi joy thank you for your reply. But i don't want to count price from ASC order . I want to add only the best fit price means it should be add with equally as i have added in the table (200, 20) and (130, 100) .. please get idea to play with array to loop 1st form the end and next loop from start.. thanks

Comment: please define what is your understanding of "best fit".

Comment: it should be average division in each package. like 20 can join with 200  not with 100 and 130 (its already (100+130)>200)

Comment: might be this page helps : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stats.php though I am still not getting your point :(